# Are simple hardcoded arithmetics cached/compiled away?

Tags: python, python-internals

I would like to know if python caches / compiles away in its .pyc files simple arithmetics like `5*5+5`.

Sometimes I like to write `if seconds > 24*60*60` for a day for example. I know that the effect on performance is unnoticeable but I'm curious nevertheless.

Comment: Note that, simply from a readability perspective, saving that calculation to a sensible identifier is the way to go. Also you aren't reliant on the implementation details then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, CPython (the default implementation of Python) uses a [peephole optimiser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peephole_optimization) to collapse such expressions into one number; this is called [*constant folding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding).

You can check for this using the [`dis` disassembler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html):

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo():
...     if seconds > 24*60*60:
...         pass
...
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (seconds)
              3 LOAD_CONST               4 (86400)
              6 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       15

  3          12 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 15)
        >>   15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note the `LOAD_CONST` instruction at offset 3; it loads the final result of the `24*60*60` expression, the expression itself is gone from the bytecode.

See the [`fold_binops_on_constants` function in the `peephole.c` file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11/Python/peephole.c#l77).